# Searching for strings in array and adding them a class

Tags: javascript

working on simple to-do-list and I'm stuck with searching tasks on list feature. User is typing in input field and I want to compare it with positions on list, if somethings fits, give it class .active (it's just font-weigth: bold;) and if it doesn't fit anymore, remove the class. For now, it is removing class only when the input field is empty and I have no idea how to edit code so it works as I want. Any ideas? [https://github.com/eryk-slowinski/to-do-list](http://github)

```
const inputAdd = document.querySelector('div.add input');
const tasksList = document.querySelector('.taskslist');

const addTask = () => {
    if (inputAdd.value) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        li.textContent = inputAdd.value;
        deleteButton.textContent = '\xD7';
        tasksList.appendChild(li).appendChild(deleteButton);
    } else return;
}

tasksList.onclick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') return;
    else e.target.parentNode.remove();
}

const searchInList = (e) => {
    const searchValue = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const liList = [...document.querySelectorAll('ul.taskslist li')].filter(li => li.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue));
    if (searchValue === "") liList.forEach(index => index.classList.remove('active'));
    else liList.forEach(index => index.classList.add('active'));
}

document.querySelector('div.add button').addEventListener('click', addTask);
document.querySelector('div.search input').addEventListener('input', searchInList);
```

Comment: Please add some relevant HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, you're only removing the class if `searchValue` is empty.

```
if (searchValue === "") liList.forEach(index => index.classList.remove('active'));
    else liList.forEach(index => index.classList.add('active'));
```

You want to move this `remove()` line to the top of the function, and simply remove all `active` classes each a character is typed into the search box, then add it back in for the new matches each time:

```
const searchInList = (e) => {
   [...document.querySelectorAll('ul.taskslist li')].forEach(li => li.classList.remove('active'));
   .....
   liList.forEach(index => index.classList.add('active'));
}
```

```js
const inputAdd = document.querySelector('div.add input');
const tasksList = document.querySelector('.taskslist');

const addTask = () => {
  if (inputAdd.value) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    li.textContent = inputAdd.value;
    deleteButton.textContent = '\xD7';
    tasksList.appendChild(li).appendChild(deleteButton);
  } else return;
}

tasksList.onclick = (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') return;
  else e.target.parentNode.remove();
}

const searchInList = (e) => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('ul.taskslist li')].forEach(li => li.classList.remove('active'));
  const searchValue = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const liList = [...document.querySelectorAll('ul.taskslist li')].filter(li => li.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue));
  liList.forEach(index => index.classList.add('active'));
}

document.querySelector('div.add button').addEventListener('click', addTask);
document.querySelector('div.search input').addEventListener('input', searchInList);
```

```css
li.active{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Things to be done</h1>
  <div class="inputs">
    <div class="add">
      <label>Add task<input type="text"></label>
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <label>Search for task<input type="text"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="counter"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <ul class="taskslist">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works :) I also added 
if (searchValue !== "") 
before the last lane of searchInList function. It is clearing class, when input field is empty.

Comment: @ErykSłowiński nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

Right now you only remove `.active` if `searchValue === ""`. You need to remove `.active` whenever state changes. You can iterate the items, and decide for each item to remove or add the class:

```
const searchInList = (e) => {
  const searchValue = e.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();

  const liList = document.querySelectorAll('ul.taskslist li')
    .forEach(li => { // iterate all items 
      if (searchValue === '' || !li.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)) { // if search term is empty or not included in li text
        li.classList.remove('active');
      } else {
        li.classList.add('active');
      }
    });
}
```